# How to send a blog post in joomla 1.6 using windows live writter?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, joomla, windows-live-writer

I am able to integrate windows live writer with joomla 1.5 but there is a problem doing the same in joomla 1.6.

Any suggestion will be appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML-RPC has been removed from Joomla 1.6 so you are going to have to do 2 things. First, you will need to install the XML-RPC library found here - http://www.cartanova.ca/code-labs/item/108-a-xml-rpc-library-extension-for-joomla-16

Next you will need to get a copy of the MovableType XML-RPC plugin and update it for J1.6. You can get that plugin from here - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-production/blog/3831